# How to avoid name clashes when composing objects

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, composition, object-design

In JavaScript you can compose objects using some kind of `extend` function.

For example I might have an [`observable`](https://github.com/Raynos/observable/blob/master/lib/observable.js) class that exposes a set of public methods (`get`, `push`, `set`, `increment`, `get`, etc)

In this case the observable also happens to be an EventEmitter so it also exposes a further set of public methods (`emit`, `on`, `removeListener`, etc)

Both of these classes have internal underscore prefixed properties that store the state. The eventemitter uses `_events` to store event handlers and the observable uses `_state` and `_id` to store state and the id.

Now when I create a model using object composition like so

```
var Model = extend({}, Observable, {
    constructor: function () {
        // Oops, I was supposed to know Observable uses the _state name already
        this._state = { ... }
    },
    someMethod: function () { ... }
})
```

This causes an issue because `Observable` already uses the `_state` internal property and there is now a name clash.

I would consider it ugly to just "have to know" what objects rely on what internal properties for the mixin to safely work.

**How do you avoid mixing in two objects which use the same internal property name?**

Ideally this would be solved with ES6 private names, but we can't do that yet and we can't emulate them without losing performance. Unless you can provide a ES6 name emulation that **does not have a large performance penalty** I'm not interested in those solutions.

An alternative would be to use closures or `bind` but then you would be recreating the functions for every instance with is a significant performance penalty. Another alternative would be to namespace internal properties as `__eventEmitter_events` and `__observable_state`. That is just ugly and reduces to probability of a namespace clash, it doesn't remove it.

Comment: If memory serves, ExtJS solves it in the object creation pipeline by instantiating an EventEmitter as a property hanging off the Observable, and proxying all *public* methods of the EventEmitter into the Observable using function binding, while maintaining all private state inside that EventEmitter. I'd code an example but I'm going AFK...give me an hour?

Comment: @zetlen note that the proxying of all public methods using function binding means your creating a whole bunch of new functions for each observable instance. as mentioned this has the exact performance penalty as emulation of private names. This is a solution, but we want to avoid it for performance reasons

Comment: I did miss that you mentioned that already, sorry! I'm not sure about your assertion that it has the "exact same" performance penalty. In all edge browsers (IE10 too) there is a native implementation of `Function.prototype.bind`. That method does return a new function, but is it as expensive as declaration? You tell me. Maybe you've already tried that!

Comment: the penalty is o(n) memory instead of o(1). the other penalty is lack of extensibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trivial solution is "namespaces"

```
var state = "Model@v0.1.3~state";
var Model = extend({}, Observable, {
    constructor: function () {
        // Nice, I used a namespace and don't clash with "Observable@v0.2.3~state"
        this[state] = { ... }
    },
    someMethod: function () { ... }
})
```